# Babel error when installing Atom and atom-typescript package

Tags: typescript, atom-editor

I am getting this odd error:

```
mydev> apm install atom-typescript
Installing atom-typescript to /Users/pitosalas/.atom/packages [BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of "/Users/pitosalas/.atom/packages/atom-typescript/dist/typescript/compiler/checker.js" as it exceeds the max of "100KB".
[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of "/Users/pitosalas/.atom/packages/atom-typescript/dist/typescript/compiler/diagnosticInformationMap.generated.js" as it exceeds the max of "100KB".
[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of "/Users/pitosalas/.atom/packages/atom-typescript/dist/typescript/compiler/emitter.js" as it exceeds the max of "100KB".
[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of "/Users/pitosalas/.atom/packages/atom-typescript/dist/typescript/compiler/parser.js" as it exceeds the max of "100KB".
[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of "/Users/pitosalas/.atom/packages/atom-typescript/dist/typescript/services/services.js" as it exceeds the max of "100KB".
✓
mydev>
```

I've seen others report it but not in the context of Typescript and Atom. Anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but not in the context of Typescript and Atom. Anyone know?

Two things:

- Atom provides `babel` as a built in transpiler. All JavaScript files get passed to babel.
- Babel removes whitespace on emit for files > 100kb (can be controlled using the `compact` option). This is why you are seeing the message.

It can be safely ignored.